# I have two tables with different dimension on column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table with different dimension on one column like this:

```
name varchar2(256 char)
```

and in table where I want to insert is

```
lastname varchar2(50 byte)
```

When I compile the next code:

```
INSERT INTO TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY
            ( FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME, EMAIL1) 
SELECT NAME,GIVEN_NAME, MAIL

FROM   glob 
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMAIL1 
                     FROM   tlp 
                     WHERE  GLOB.mail = TLP.email1 ) 
         AND GLOB.mail IS NOT NULL ) 
        OR ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid
                         FROM   TLP 
                         WHERE GLOB.LOGIN = TLP.userid ) 
             AND GLOB.mail IS NULL )
  AND GLOB.COUNTRY='France';
```

I have the next error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEST"."TLP"."LASTNAME" (actual: 53, maximum: 50)
12899. 00000 -  "value too large for column %s (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"
```

My question is: How I can do this insert possible, having in mind the fact as I don't have the permission to modify the structure of column with ALTER.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot insert 256 characters into a 50 character field, obviously. If you can't alter the table and are willing to live with the data loss, you could truncate the column's value using [`substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm):

```
INSERT INTO TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY
            ( FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME, DEPARTMENT, TELEPHONE1, EMAIL1, USERID, DATECREATED) 
SELECT SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 50), GIVEN_NAME, DEPARTMENT, PHONE, MAIL, LOGIN, SYSDATE 
FROM   gal 
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMAIL1 
                     FROM   TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY 
                     WHERE  GAL.mail = TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY.email1 ) 
         AND GAL.mail IS NOT NULL ) 
        OR ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid
                         FROM   TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY 
                         WHERE  gAL.LOGIN = TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY.userid ) 
             AND GAL.mail IS NULL )
  AND GAL.COUNTRY='France';
```

Comment: @PopDaniela I don't understand the question. Can you try to clarify it?

Comment: sorry but when I compiled this code the same error appear

Comment: This is substringing the first name, but it is the last name that has the problem.  Apply the SUBSTR to the second selected column: `SELECT NAME, SUBSTR(GIVEN_NAME, 1, 50), …`

Comment: ok i know that, but when i compile the error was the same, for lastname .